# Angular2 - How to chain async http requests and stop if fails

Tags: angular, http, typescript, observable

I have an array of HTTP requests that I need to fire in certain order, but if any of the previous one fails then none of the following ones is going to be executed.

1. How can I achieve that?
2. What's the best approach?

I need something like:

```
  let failed: boolean = false;
  payloadArray.forEach(payload => {
     if (!failed) {
     http.post(this.url, payload, this.options)
     .map((res: Response) => {
        return res.json;
      })
    .catch((error: any) => {
          failed = true;
          Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')
       });
     }
  }
```

Comment: FYI: `Observable.throw` doesn't actually throw. It has to be the return value from `catch` if you want to propagate an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would require an Observable creator that merged the emitted values, but only subscribed in sequence after each completed. I don't think there is anything like that in the RxJs library.

I did write a factory method that I think would yield what you want:

```
public sequence(requests: Array<Observable<Response>>): Observable<Response[]> {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
        const output = [];

        function executeHttp() {
            const request = requests.pop();
            if (request) {
                request.take(1).subscribe((value) => {
                    output.push(value);
                    executeHttp();
                }, (ex) => {
                    observer.error(ex);
                });
            } else {
                observer.next(output);
                observer.complete();
            }
        }

        executeHttp();
    });
}
```

Note that I added a `take(1)` operator to the HTTP observables. This was done to have the HTTP observables destroyed after they yield a response. So that you don't have to call unsubscribe. You can use `take(1)` or `first()` which do the same thing, but they work differently when there is nothing emitted.

If you find operators that do what you want. Please let me know.